# Patching bazaar explorer

Tags: explorer, bazaar

In launching bazar explorer in macosx, a common error arises when i try to view the repository, it say "too many files", a solution has been posted by using a patch over at bazars website (https://bugs.launchpad.net/bzr-explorer/+bug/926439)

.... My question is how do you exactly patch them? I typed "bzr patch " but errors occured, am i missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

The patch applies to the source code of bzr-explorer. You would have to download the source, apply the patch to that and then install it from the patched source.

In detail:

1. Download [bzr-explorer](https://launchpad.net/bzr-explorer/1.2/1.2.3/+download/bzr-explorer-1.2.3.tar.gz) and the [patch](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bzr-explorer/+bug/926439/+attachment/2769232/+files/workaround-926439.patch).
2. Extract bzr-explorer into a directory which you can access easily from Terminal.
3. Copy the downloaded patch file into the same directory.
4. Open Terminal and change to that directory.
5. Execute the following commands:

   `patch < workaround-926439.patch`

   `python setup.py install`

Comment: are there steps to help us non terminal savy guys?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include detailed steps. I haven't tested the steps but they should work.